# WPF Dialog - Allow interaction with underlying windows

Tags: wpf, xaml, dialog, info

Is it possible with WPF to open a dialog (a new window) and keep the possibility to interact with the underlying main window?

I imagine a help window that is placed next to the main window and doesn't block interaction.

How could I easily check where the mouse is over and show a info to the specific area?

Comment: Not sure I'm following this, If you want a "dialog" that does not block the `MainWindow`, why call `.ShowDialog()` to begin-with? why not just use `.Show()?` what's the difference of this Window to another normal `Window`? you got the `Parent` property of `Window` to work with as well which doesn't tie into this.

Comment: You got me into the right direction, I just haven't been aware of the existence of the simple .Show() because my framework didn't use that.
I'm now able to interact with both windows at the same time.
And how can I place the window relative to the parent? You can post this as answer, I will accept it as the correct one

Comment: You can set `window.Owner = parentWindow` and `window.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner` properties if you want it to be centered relative to the parent. If you need some specific position then `window.Top` and `window.Left` properties.

Comment: Thank you two, both answers helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could call `.Show()` and set the `Topmost` Property to true.

> A window whose Topmost property is set to true appears above all
>   windows whose Topmost properties are set to false.
>
> In the group of windows that have Topmost property is set to true, the
>   window that is currently activated is the topmost window. Likewise for
>   the group of windows that have Topmost property is set to false.
>   See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.topmost.aspx